# Redux callback to function when user interacts with button

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

****DISCLAIMER**** I just started using Redux yesterday >.<

I have a confirmation modal (image below), that can be called from every component on my app and I'm using Redux to achieve this.

[image: My confirmation modal]

The problem is that the 'Yes' button is suposed to call a function that can be diferent in every component. I achieved this by passing a function in the action of the reducer and storing it in the state. But this solution isn't correct, because we cannot store functions in a store state (even though it worked...).

**My question is:** How can I define a diferent function for every component that uses this modal and call that function when the user clicks on the Yes button? Is Redux the best approach to this?

This is my modal code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, } from "reactstrap";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
  hide,
  show,
  clicarConfirmar,
  selectshowConfirmar,
  selectBackdrop,
  selectMessage,
} from './feature/ModalSlice';

function ModalConfirmacao() {
  const modalShow = useSelector(selectshowConfirmar);
  const backdrop = useSelector(selectBackdrop);
  const message = useSelector(selectMessage);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button> */}
      <Modal isOpen={modalShow} toggle={() => dispatch(show())} backdrop={backdrop}>
        <ModalHeader style={{ backgroundColor: '#d00000', color: 'white' }} toggle={() => dispatch(hide())}>Atention</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          {message}
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="success" onClick={() => dispatch(clicarConfirmar()).then()}>Sim</Button>
          <Button color="secundary" onClick={() => dispatch(hide())}>Não</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );

}
```

This is my reducer slice code. Bare in mind that this slice is used by other modals.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'modal',
  initialState: {
    showError: false,
    showAtencao: false,
    showSuccess: false,
    showConfirmar: false,
    backdrop: true,
    message: 'Ocorreu um erro.',
    clicouConfirmar: false,
    // funcConfirmar: undefined,
  },
  reducers: {
    show: (state, action) => {
      if (action) {
        if (action.payload) {
          if (action.payload.tipo) {
            switch (action.payload.tipo) {
              case 'erro':
              case 'Erro':
                state.showError = true;
                break;
              case 'sucesso':
              case 'Sucesso':
                state.showSuccess = true;
                break;
              case 'atencao':
              case 'Atencao':
                state.showAtencao = true;
                break;
              case 'confirm':
              case 'Confirm':
                state.showConfirmar = true;
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          }
          if (action.payload.backdrop) {
            state.backdrop = action.payload.backdrop
          }
          if (action.payload.message) {
            state.message = action.payload.message
          }
          // if(action.payload.funcConfirmar){
          //     state.funcConfirmar = action.payload.funcConfirmar
          // }
        }
      }
    },
    hide: state => {
      state.showError = false;
      state.showSuccess = false;
      state.showAtencao = false;
      state.showConfirmar = false;
      state.backdrop = true;
      state.message = '';
      state.clicouConfirmar = false;
      // state.funcConfirmar =  undefined;
    },
    confirmar: state => {
      state.clicouConfirmar = true;
      state.showConfirmar = false;
    }
  },
});

export const { show, hide, confirmar } = slice.actions;

export const clicarConfirmar = (action) => dispatch => {
  return Promise.resolve(dispatch(confirmar(action)))
};

export const selectBackdrop = state => state.modal.backdrop;
export const selectShowError = state => state.modal.showError;
export const selectShowAtencao = state => state.modal.showAtencao;
export const selectShowSuccess = state => state.modal.showSuccess;
export const selectshowConfirmar = state => state.modal.showConfirmar;
export const selectMessage = state => state.modal.message;
export const selectClicouConfirmar = state => state.modal.clicouConfirmar;

export default slice.reducer;
```

**EDIT**

This is the way I'm calling the modal, inside a function after some logic:

```
this.props.show({type: 'confirm', message: 'Are you sure you want to continue?', backdrop:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using redux. For that pass function as prop to your Modal component for eg :

In your Component create your function :

```
onYesClick=()=>{
    //your function code that should get executed on button click
}
<Component>
  <ModalComponent onYes={this.onYesClick}>
<Component>
```

Now in Modal Component, on click of the yes button call this prop function by

```
this.props.onYes();
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I have a solution that is the way you are saying, but i was wondering if it was possible with redux and this way i just need to put the ModalComponent in the "main page" of my app once and call it from there. But probably redux is overkill to achieve this

Comment: In that case, you can create a state in redux with a componentName and on every click to open that modal call that action creator to set componentName and on click of "Yes" you can check the value of componentName and can conditionally call the respective functions

Comment: how can i conditionally check if the value was changed on the component that called the modal?

Comment: Everytime your modal gets called from a component , dispatch an action say this.props.setComponentName("componentName")